# Missing required parameter for Route Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

i want to edit Post with new controller name **StaffController** but error Missing required parameter for Route

> Missing required parameter for [Route: verification.update] [URI:
> verification/{verification}] [Missing parameter: verification].

**Controller**

```
public function edit(Request $request, Post $post)
{

    $choices = Choice::all();
    $pets = Pet::all();
    $types = Type::all();
    $vehicles = Vehicle::all();
    $genders = Gender::all();
    $reasons = Reason::all();
    $posts = Post::all();
    
    return view('dashboard.staff.edit',compact('post', 'types', 'vehicles', 'pets', 'choices', 'genders', 'reasons'));
}

public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
{ 
    $request->validate([
        'phonenumber' => 'required',
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();

    if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
        $destinationPath = 'image/';
        $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
        $input['image'] = "$profileImage";
    }else{
        unset($input['image']);
    }
      
    $post->update($input);
    
    return back()->with('success', 'Post verification successfully.');
}

public function destroy(Post $post, $id)
{
    $this->authorize('isStaff');
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $post->delete();
    return back()->with('success','Post deleted successfully');
}
```

Route

```
Route::resource('verification', StaffController::class);
```

View

```
<form action="{{ route('verification.update', ['verification'=>$post->id]) }}" x-data="{types: {{$post->type_id}}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
```

Route List
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwbFH.png)

Comment: You're sending an `id` in the action where in the controller you're asking for a `Post` object. Maybe removing the type of `$post` in the update function

Answer (score 1):

Since your routes are:

```php
Route::resource('verification', StaffController::class);
```

You need your controller method to use the right arguments name:

```php
public function edit(Post $verification)
{

}

public function update(Request $request, Post $verification)
{

}
```

That's because Laravel is trying to resolve your bindings with the arguments name.

What's happening:

- Laravel cannot find `Post $post` in your edit method (because of the reason above, it should be `Post $verification` or you should rename your routes and replace `verifications` by `posts`)
- It creates an empty instance of `Post` instead
- It sends this empty instance to the view
- You are using this empty instance to build your route in your form action attribute
- Since it's empty, `$post->id` returns null, so there is no parameter names `verification` in your url... which leads to

```
Missing required parameter for [Route: verification.update] 
[URI: verification/{verification}] [Missing parameter: verification].
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::resource('verification', StaffController::class)->name('verification');
```

You can try this.